# Is every bounded operator normal?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, self-adjoint-operators, positive-matrices

Let $A: {\scr H} \to {\scr H}$ be a linear bounded endomorphism on a Hilbert space $\scr H$, in brief:
$A \in {\frak B} ({\scr H})$.

If it's true that $\ \forall A \in {\frak B} ({\scr H}) \quad A^*A \in {\frak B} ({\scr H}) $ and $A^*A \geq 0 $, which implies $A^*A$ self-adjoint (every positive bounded operator is self-adjoint), and hence $A^*A=A A^*$ ($^*$ is an antilinear involution)

Then  $\ \forall A \in {\frak B} ({\scr H}) \quad A^*A=AA^*$, which is precisely the definition of normal operator.

So **every bounded linear operator is normal**. It can't be true... yet I don't see the error.

Comment: $(A^*A)^*  = A^* A^{**} = A^*A \neq A A^*$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A^*A$ is self-adjoint, not $A$ itself. So we can conclude
$$(A^* A)^*(A^* A) = (A^* A)(A A^*)^*$$
for any $A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$, which is an entirely more reasonable proposition.

Comment: But.. isn't it true that $(ST)^* = T^*S^* \quad (\forall T, S \in {\frak B} ({\scr H}))$?

Comment: Yes, that's true (but I'm not sure where you're going with it).

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In general, $ A^*A=AA^*$ is not true !

For example let ${\scr H}= \ell^2$ and $A$ given by $A(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(0,x_1,x_2,x_3,...).$